# How long must a US passport be valid when visiting Brazil?

Tags: us-citizens, visa-free-entry, passport-renewals, brazil

I am planning to visit friends in Brazil in March 2020.  My US passport expires in May 2020.  From what I can gather online, Brazil requires passports to be valid for six months after arrival if you are applying for a visitor visa.  However, since June 2019, US citizens are not required to obtain a visa to visit Brazil.  I have not been able to find any clear guidance online concerning the required length of passport validity for citizens of visa-exempt countries.

Can I travel to Brazil on a US passport that expires two months after my visit, or do I need to renew my passport before my trip?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The website of the Brazilian Consulate in NYC states](http://novayork.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/visa_requirements_by_country.xml):

> Brazil also has visa waiver agreements with certain countries. For the visa waivers listed below to be in effect, the foreign traveler must bear a passport issued by the country with which Brazil has a visa waiver agreement. In addition to that, **the foreign passport must be valid for at least 6 months throughout the trip**.

So it is not just enough to have 6 month validity at entry, but 6 month + length of stay! You should renew your passport before you travel.

Answer (score 4):

I am Brazilian and this is the info I found:

> TURISTAS
>
> Passaporte válido (válido por pelo menos mais seis meses no momento da
> entrada no Brasil). Também é altamente recomendável que o passaporte
> seja válido por mais de 6 meses no momento da saída.
>
> Prova de alojamento, prova de meios de subsistência para o tempo de permanência
> no Brasil e bilhete de retorno.
>
> Estes documentos podem ser solicitados no momento da entrada no Brasil e a incapacidade de apresentar esses documentos podem, eventualmente, levar às autoridades fronteiriças brasileiras a negar a entrada no país.
>
> Para mais informações sobre estes documentos, entre em contato com a Embaixada do Brasil mais próxima da sua residência

So yes, you can be denied entry into Brazil if your passport is less than 6 months from its expiration date.

Comment: Welcome to the network! For context, where did you find this information? Could you include a link to the source as well as the actual text? Thank you.

Comment: [This might be the source](https://brazil.diplomatie.belgium.be/pt-br/entrada-permanencia-e-saida-do-brasil-turistas-homens-de-negocios-e-os-menores-da-belgica-ao-brasil), looks like a kind of an official site

Comment: No, that's the Brazilian embassy's site in Belgium, addressed to Belgian tourists.

Comment: Yes, that's the source. But that's a general rule... the same was told to me when I came to Chile